# I've ran into a syntax error in vba code for an Excel web query based on a table

Tags: vba, excel, web

I am trying to update a Macro that I recorded so that content from the lines in the spreadsheet will update the web query target but have run into a a few errors.  I've sorted through several of them but the current issue is a Runtime error.  The following is the code for my query:

```
Sub GetAllPkgInfo()

  Sheets("AllPkgs").Select
  Range("A2").Select

  Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    Call PkgInfo1
  Loop


End Sub



Sub PkgInfo1()
'
' PkgInfo1 Macro
' Import RHEL package information from RPMFind
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
'
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("WebQuery").Select
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
    Range("$G$1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="URL;https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=" & _
       Range("$G$1").Value, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "search.php?query=abrt_1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "2"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -5).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("AllPkgs").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("CombinedPackages[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("WebQuery").Select
    ActiveCell.Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.QueryTable.Delete
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets("AllPkgs").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("CombinedPackages[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
End Sub
```

The error message I receive states "Runtime error '1004': Paste Method of Worksheet Class Failed" and highlights the first code instance of

```
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Can anybody help me get straightened out please?

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I get a Compile Error: Syntax Error message highlighting the line:                                     
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=" & range("G1")""), Destination:=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:= "URL;https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=" & _
       Range("G1").Value, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```